# Is there a way to store registered devices FCM tokens in Firebase Console?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to be able to see registered FCM tokens in Firebase Console so that I can send specific test notifications. Is there a way to setup Firebase to store the FCM tokens locally in the Firebase project?

If the solution is to add codes to the app, that may be a problem for me as I am using an external app developer to develop my app and he is currently unavailable to make any changes in the app.

So I am just looking for a way for me to easily see all registered FCM tokens within the Firebase Console.

Comment: The FCM tokens have to be stored to some server that you would be hosting. Only this would allow you to send notifications there after. You could take it from there.

Comment: That is correct, and sounds like an answer Dinesh. :) 

@Allie: Firebase does not have an API to provide a list of known FCM tokens. You'll have to store such a list yourself, which is sometimes called a token registry.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have now created an API endpoint to store the FCM tokens to my server. How do I mark this post as answered?